# WM_DESTROY, WM_CLOSE bypassing IMessageFilter

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, message-queue, imessagefilter

Below is my message filter:

```
bool MyFilter::PreFilterMessage(Message %m){
    switch(m.Msg){
    case WM_CLOSE:
    case WM_DESTROY:
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
    case WM_QUIT:
        Debug::WriteLine(L"Gone!");
        break;
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        Debug::WriteLine(L"A mouse! Catch! Catch!!! CATCH!!");
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I verified that I am filtering most messages without a problem. However, I am not receiving any messages dispatched after the window's close button is clicked (`WM_CLOSE`, `WM_DESTROY`, `WM_NCDESTROY` and `WM_QUIT`). Why is this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage() is only called for messages in the message queue.  Messages like WM_CLOSE are sent directly to WndProc() with SendMessage(), they bypass the queue.  You also won't get messages like WM_ACTIVATE, WM_GETTEXT, etc.  Input events, that's about it.

Comment: What about WM_LBUTTONDOWN? And where can I find out which messages are sent directly to the WndProc and which ones are posted to the message queue?

Comment: WM_LBUTTONDOWN is usually posted, not sent.  It depends on the code generating the message.